# Does anybody knows the scale that Crystal Report uses?

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, scale, rpt

I'm trying get the height and width of a field in a crystal report but i don't know the scale that uses, if is in inch or cm or which.

Maybe is a silly question, but i can't find the specification of the scale of the .rpt =(

Anybody knows?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Probably twips: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip

Comment: Crystal Reports uses twips: 1440 twips = 1 inch